# Why is my raspberry pi self-hosted website stalling for over 10 seconds inconsistently?

Tags: node.js, performance, express, raspberry-pi, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building my first website. [Full source code available here.](https://github.com/SalvadorSTM/My-Website)

When I access my website from its local ip in my home network it loads almost instantly, but when I access it through the domain name imsalvador.com (google domain) it sometimes stalls for around 10 seconds.

[image]

I am running my NodeJs Express website with pm2 on a raspberry pi 3b+, from my really good gigabit fiber internet.

I don't think it's chrome's 6 connection limit thats causing the long wait, as this has happened on many different devices ive tested from.

This is the only thing im running on my pi, so resources should not be an issue.

**Important Details**

1. This is a NodeJs Express website
2. Using certificate from Lets Encrypt to run with SSL
3. Domain is from google domains, forwarding all http traffic to **https**://www.imsalvador.com/
4. Using google Dynamic DNS API to provide my ip to google
5. Iptables forwarding traffic from port `443 (https)` to `3001` (chosen listening port in app.js).
6. Simple sendFile when `"/"` is requested `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");`
7. Top reporting healthy resources
8. Rasp Pi 3b+ CPU has 4 cores, so I have pm2 running with 3 cores, and load balancing between them.
9. Same behavior happens with docker node image, pm2, and node app.js
10. Running express debug shows that the content is being delivered very fast after the get request is received.
11. Running latest raspbian (pi os)
12. Using eth0 interface

Comment: There could be hundreds of causes of this.....just because you have a gigabit connection does not mean it is symmetric, your router could be interfering with requests, your application could not be configured correctly and so needs to "spin up" on certain requests instead of constantly running,  you could have multiple simultaneous requests and the storage (SD card?) might not have random read capabilities that can keep up. Your ISP may even be interfering as it is likely against their terms and conditions. Hopefully the suggestions above at least give you a starting point.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie According to [AT&T forums](https://forums.att.com/conversations/att-fiber-account/website-hosting/5df01823bad5f2f606bbcbb5), residential customers are free to host web servers from their homes. I was afraid it could be a modem problem. I have have no idea where I would start to debug something like that.